Functoriality of a Galois topos construction
This question is about the generalization of Grothendieck Galois theory to topoi.
I understand that there is some nuance about the correct definition of Galois topos. But in his paper "On the representation theory of Galois and Atomic Topoi" (see section 5.1) Eduardo J. Dubuc presents a construction of Galois Topos $\mathsf{GLC}(\mathcal{E})$ for a Grothendieck topos $\mathcal{E}$. $\mathsf{GLC}(\mathcal{E})$ is constructed as inverse limit of sheaves $\mathsf{Split}(U)$ locally constant for a certain cover $U$ of $1_{\mathcal{E}}$. So, $\mathsf{GLC}(\mathcal{E})$ is a category generated by all all locally constant sheaves and Dubuc claims that it is a quotient of $\mathcal{E}$. And there is a geometric surjection $\mathcal{E} \twoheadrightarrow \mathsf{GLC(\mathcal{E})}$. Basically, I want to use this definition for now
I'm wondering, if there is a geometric morphism $f : \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{F}$, is there
any morphism $\mathsf{GLC}(f) : \mathsf{GLC}(\mathcal{E}) \to \mathsf{GLC}(\mathcal{F})$?
Is the construction $\mathsf{GLC}(\mathcal{E})$ functorial? What if $f$ belongs to some nice class of geometric morphisms, e. g. it is connected.
Clearly the inverse limit itself is functorial, but the inverse limit is taken over objects of form $\mathsf{Split}(U)$ and collections of covers are different for $1_{\mathcal{E}}$ and $1_{\mathcal{F}}$. Dubuc writes that for a connected geometric morphism $f$ the object $X \in \mathcal{E}$ is Gallois iff $f^* X$ is. So it seems, that iff both $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ are connected and locally connected, the connected geometric morphism $f$
should define geometric morphism of locally constant sheaves. I'm not sure about $f_*$ part of $f$.
